# Loading google realtime api js on server or offline

Tags: google-drive-realtime-api

I was excited to see that the Google Realtime API has offline / in-memory support now, but I'm wondering how to load the script. Is there anything like an npm module for it, or do I have to fetch it with `gapi` every time I want to use it?

Answer (score 0):

It is not available as a standalone module.  You have to fetch it as some point, although you could cache it locally for some time.  Just be sure not to let it get too far out of date, so it doesn't get out of sync with the server.

For example, you are expecting to be offline at some point, you could maintain a cache of it, and update it every time you come online.

Comment: Thanks for your response Cheryl! The docs mention using the in-memory mode in tests or on the server, but the script I use for my web-client seems to download something that relies on `window`. Can you expound a little about how to fetch & use the script outside a browser/

Comment: I'd like to know about this too.